# Flex 3 tilelist not scolling with 'bottom' property set

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, tilelist

Pretty basic issue but it seems strange it wouldn't work. My tile list scrolls vertically. If I set an explicit height everything works fine. If I set the height to a percentage or I set the bottom property, the tile list wont shrink smaller than the height of the renderers times the number of rows that are displayed.

The solution I came up with is to listen for the resize event of the parent and set the height explicitly of the tile list every time. It works but I'm curious if this is normal or if something else is going on here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the tile list wont shrink smaller than the height of the renderers times the number of rows that are displayed.

This is probably expected. Since you have not shown any code, I will guess that you are setting height to 100% or bottom="0". Even if you specify something slightly smaller, like 90% or bottom="10", its going to make the list be big enough to fill the specified space.

If you want scrollbars you can always force them by specifying a `maxHeight`.

Comment: "if you specify something slightly smaller, like 90% or bottom="10", its going to make the list be big enough to fill the specified space."
That is the behavior that I'm not sure what the reason is for. It seems that regardless of what attribute I use to specify a height, relative or not it should respect that.
The maxHeight didn't work since the tileList's container can change height but I did just explicitly set the height on the resize of the container.

Comment: @ScottF I'm not sure, but maybe you were trying to specify the size of a component that was lower than the component's minimumHeight? Flex components calculate a minimum size based on the data supplied to them and the parameters you set on the component (like the # of rows requested). On re-reading your question, I am wondering if this is what was happening?